# How to convert NPDA to PDA?

Tags: pushdown-automata

I have been given this  Nondeterministic pushdown automata and I need to convert it to deterministic pushdown automata, I have been stuck with this for a while now, I know that there cant be transitions where the pda doesnt read anything from the stack but i dont know how to solve this.
[image: NPDA]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not all Class 2 languages can be represented by a PDA

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your stack alphabet is $\Gamma =\left\{Z_0,X\right\}$. You can eliminate transitions which don't pop stack, by guessing which stack symbol is at the top. like this:

before: 
$(a,\epsilon)/XXX$

after: 
$(a, X)/XXXX$, and 
$(a, Z_0)/XXXZ_0$

Comment: @JohnKnot123 if it helps you please set it as accepted